# why a field in the report it shown as id?

Tags: reporting, security

I got the same report in internal user and in community user and country relationship its shown as country name with internal user and its sown as id for the community user.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It may not have access to the Name field, can you check that?

Comment: already checked, not field level security, its also standard report

Comment: did you check it on community users profile?

Comment: Yes, there are all fields on Visible, i can see the column but its id and not name, its weird